# iOS how can I create a custom "keyboard"? (just in one field of my app)

Tags: ios

I want to create something like this in a field I have, a "custom keyboard". How can I do that?
Image: [image]

Thanks.

Comment: Why is this necessarily a "keyboard"? It's not triggered by tapping a UITextField or UITextView by your example. The way I see it - you want to create a panel that slides in from the bottom once you tap on a UITableViewCell in your UITableView, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumption: Your custom keyboard would be similar in the types of options offered to the one pictured.

If you're not wed to the layout you have above, I would personally recommend a [UIPickerView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html) (as Apple uses when creating calendar events, etc).

One of the advantages of doing so is that it is a UI component that is well understood by users in the iOS world, whereas a custom keyboard interface would not only be harder to implement, but would have a higher learning curve as users are presented with an interface they've never seen before.

Comment: Guess you are right :D

Answer (score 1):

The example you showing is here is no real keyboard - most likely it is a custom `UIView` with a rather complicated `UIControl` elements and `UIButtons` behind it that were made to look like the more or less standard iOS interface. So you need no keyboard in this case, just use your imagination!

Answer (score 1):

Any view can be an `inputView` for a UITextField.